# Jasmine test angular $http.get rejection which throws error

Tags: angularjs, http, get, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'm testing many existing services of my job's core platform, and I have a service which throws error when the $http call does not succeed:
Here's the code:

```
function getConfiguration(configurationType) {
    var parameters = {
        res: configurationType,
        host: $location.host()
    };

    return $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        params: parameters,
        paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'
    })
        .then(
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.data;
            },
            function (error) {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            });
}
```

And here is my Jasmine test:

```
it('reject api call', function () {
    httpBackend.whenGET(/(.*)(\/configuration)\?(.*)/g).respond(400, {error: 'error_msg'});

    expect(function () {
       configurationService.getConfiguration('publicserviceslist');
    }).toThrow();

    httpBackend.flush();
});
```

The error i've been receiving is:

```
Expected function to throw an exception.
```

I do not want to throw an exception. I'm using [this](https://ajsblackbelt.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/jasmine-tests-expect-tothrow/comment-page-1/) post as a guide, but I can't figure out what it's going o with my code.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you all.